# How to have a clickable button

Tags: html, css, button

I have a text link as "Click Me To Get There" that I transformed into a button via CSS.

This is what I used successfully:

```css
.product-buttons-container {
  background-color: #ff6347;
  padding: 11px 24px;
  line-height: 17px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

.product-buttons-container:hover {
  background-color: #E5423A;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="product-buttons-container">Click Me To Get There</a>
```

The problem with that is that only the text still has the "a" tag with the destination URL. The area of the button is just look-and-feel and, although on mouse-hover the cursor change as pointer there is no link in the button padding.

What am I missing in order to get a fully clickable button?

Comment: Feels like an XY problem to me: if you want the entire thing to be clickable, then change your DOM so that the `<a>` tag wraps whatever text you want to be clickable. Using `cursor: pointer` is just a cosmetic fix and CSS does not allow you to programmatically modify element behaviors. So either update the DOM, or use JS to bind a click event listener to that element you're styling (the former is way simpler and better).

Answer (score 2):

The `<a>` tag has `display: inline` as default. You can make it `display: inline-block` or `display: block` to adjust the size of the element. As user Terry already pointed out, you can use `cursor: pointer` to style the cursor (it won't be necessary though if you use an `<a>` tag.)

You can either:

**Style the `<a>` itself like a button**

```css
.button-link {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: silver;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" class="button-link">I can be a button, too</a>
```

**Wrap the `<button>` with a link element**

```css
.button-link {
  background-color: silver;
}

button {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" class="button-link"><button>I am clickable</button></a>
```

**Use `<button>` with JS and onclick (not recommended)**

```js
document.body.onload = function() {
  let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-link]');
  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    let button = buttons[i];
    button.onclick = function() {
      window.location.href = button.dataset.link;
    }
  }
}();
```

```css
.button {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: silver;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" data-link="https://www.google.com">I am a link, too</button>
```

You don't even have to use `<a>` or `<button>` you could link whatever element you like. You can always add a link with the `onclick` attribute in javascript.

**Here is a link in a bigger context:**

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: silver;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<p>This represents some text on a website la-di-da
  <a class="button" href="#">this whole box shall be linked and act like a button</a> and after the link it just goes on ...
</p>
<p>Some other paragraph</p>
```